# Change page in phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

After that the android app in eclipse with phonegap has loaded the first page, how can it move to another page in the same project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep it on the same HTML page but you use javascript onclick events to show / hide different divs

Comment: This is bad solution if you have many pages because each hide/show or any animation you do is going to redraw the entire page... very inefficient.

Comment: This is referring to phonegap as it was two and a half years ago. In the meant time I learn native app programming because phoneGap was unable to do things I needed to do. On top of which the html is only rendered once unless you are using ajax using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is just HTML and JS, so either read `http://www.web-source.net/html_redirect.htm` or `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.location` depending how you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This Google Maps [tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1) with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile includes using jQuery Mobile's $.mobile.changePage